# We get data with ORDER BY ASC but NOT BY DESC

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We got multiple odd scenarios.

For example:

a) We are unable to order by _ts : empty results

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY data._ts DESC
```

b) We can ORDER BY ASC and we get Results(more than >100). But if we ORDER BY DESC we get Zero results, has no sense for us :( ,

Assuming that `c` is an integer, this is the behavior we are seeing:

```
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY data.c ASC  = RESULTS
SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY data.c DESC = zero results
```

c) We have an UDF to do contains insesitive, but is not working for all cases, JS function its tested outside and IT is working, we don't understand
SELECT * FROM data r where udf.TEST(r.c, "AS")  = RESULTS
SELECT * FROM data r where udf.TEST(r.c, "health")  =  zero results (but by other field I can find tha value)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It should help you frame your questions better. Better framed questions usually attract more answers.

Comment: Now to answer your question: Are you checking for continuation tokens when you get back the result? Is indexing enabled on the collection you are querying?

Comment: Please create a separate question for the UDF issue.

Comment: You also need to make sure that indexing is a range index as opposed to a hash index and the index has enough precision for all possible values. The easiest way to accomplish this last is to use -1 for the precision which specifies to use every available bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*jamesjara and I synced offline... posting our discussion here for everyone else's benefit :)*

**1) Query response limits and continuation tokens**

There are limits for how long a query will execute on DocumentDB. These limits include the query's resource consumption (you can ballpark this w/ the amount of provisioned RU/sec * 5 sec + an undisclosed buffer), response size (1mb), and timeout (5 sec).

If these limits are hit, then a partial set of results may be returned. The work done by the query execution is preserved by passing the state back in the form of a continuation token (`x-ms-continuation` in the HTTP response header). You can resume the execution of the query by passing the continuation token in a follow-up query. The Client SDKs make this interaction easier by automatically paging through results via `toList()` or `toArray()` (depending on the SDK flavor).

It's possible to get an empty page in the result. This can happen when the resource consumption limit is reached before the query engine finds the first result (e.g. when *scanning* through a collection to look for few documents in a large dataset).

**2) ORDER BY and Index Policies**

In order to use `ORDER BY` or range comparisons (`<`, `>`, etc) within your queries, you should specify an index policy that contains a Range index with the maximum precision (precision = -1) over the JSON properties used to sort with. This allows the query engine to take advantage of an index.

Otherwise, you can force a scan by specifying the `x-ms-documentdb-query-enable-scan` HTTP request header w/ the value set to `true`. In the client SDKs, this is exposed via the `FeedOptions` object.

Suggested Index Policy for `ORDER BY`:

```
{
  "indexingMode": "consistent",
  "automatic": true,
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        },
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "String",
          "precision": -1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "path": "/_ts/?",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "kind": "Range",
          "dataType": "Number",
          "precision": -1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": []
}
```

**3) UDFs and indexing**

UDFs are not able to take advantage of indexes, and will result in a scan. Therefore, it is advised to include additional filters in your queries `WHERE` clause to reduce the amount of documents to be scanned.

Comment: Is it required to add a separate index for path "/_ts/?"? Won't be _ts indexed by number range index defined for path "/*"? Examples from the documentation don't clarify this moment